# how to calculate one column from another columns?

Tags: sql, database-connection, create-table, calculated-columns, monetdb

In monetdb I created a table:

```
create table extractedcatalog(id int, ra double, decl double, x double, y double, z double);
```

`ra,decl` are all inserted into tables already, now I want to calculate `x,y,z` from `ra,decl` columns. In sql I executed like this:

```
update extractedcatalog set x = (cos(radians(decl))*cos(radians(ra)));
```

but i got response:

> connection terminated

Is there any problem with my sql query?

Thanks very much!

Comment: most likely your table is huge. When you execute your query, the database engine creates a big transaction log. The update statement takes time longer then the query timeout set in your system. Try increasing the timeout

Comment: the query seems correct to me !! try increasing query timeout as said above

Answer (score 0):

Please indicate your platform and MonetDB version. A Connection Termination message indicates a loss of contact between your client and server. You may look into the Merovingian log file for further clues on the underlying cause.